# error in fortran program

Tags: fortran90

This is my simple fortran program

```
program accel
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(5000) ::a,b,c
    integer i
    real t1,t2
    do i=1,5000
    a(i)=i+1
    b(i)=i+2
    end do

     call cpu_time(t1)
    do i=1,5000
    c(i)=a(i)*b(i)
    end do
     call cpu_time(t2)

    write (*,*)'Elapsed CPU time = ',t2-t1,'seconds'

end program accel
```

but cpu time shows 0.0000 sec. why?

Comment: Because it's very fast! Note that 0.0000 is not actually zero. It's just < 0.00005

Comment: ok..so what i can do to measure very less time

Comment: lets say for above program if i want to calculate cpu time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Use this to display your answer:

```
write(*,'(A,F12.10,A)')'Elapsed CPU time = ',t2-t1,' seconds.'
```

### Longer answer

There can be at least two reasons why you get zero as suggested in the answers of @Ernest Friedman-Hill and @Klas Lindbäck:

1. The computation is taking less than 0.00005 seconds
2. The compiler optimizes away the whole loop

In  the first case, you have a few options:

1. You can display more digits of `t2-t1` using a format like I gave you above, or alternatively you can print the result in milliseconds: `1000*(t2-t1)`
2. Add more iterations: if you do 50000 iterations instead of 5000, it should take ten times longer.
3. Make each iteration longer: you can replace your multiplication by a sequence of complicated operations possibly using math functions

In the second case, you can:

1. Disable optimization by passing the appropriate flag to your compiler (`-O0` for gfortran)
2. Use `c` somewhere in your program after the loop

I compiled your program using gfortran 4.2.1 on OS X Lion and it worked out of the box (displaying time in exponential notation) and the formatting (short answer) worked fine too. I tried enabling and disabling optimization and it worked fine too.

The accuracy of `cpu_time` is probably platform dependent so that may also explain different behaviors across different machines, but with all this you should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't take very long to do 5000 multiplications -- it may simply be taking less than one unit of `cpu_time()`'s resolution. Crank that 5000 up to 100000 or so, and then you'll likely see something.

Answer (score 1):

The optimiser has seen that c is never read, so the calculation of c can be skipped. 
If you print the value of c, the loop willnot be optimised away.